# UWP project needs to be deployed before it can be started

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, visual-studio-2017, configurationmanager

I am using visual studio 2017, created a new xamarin forms project and tried to run the UWP project. It shows the following error:

*the project  needs to be deployed before it can be started. verify the project is selected to be deployed the solution configuration manager, or deploy it explicitly by clinking one of the deploy commands in the build menu.*

I have looked at all online solutions and only found that you need to set the cpu to x86 and to check the deploy checkbox under the configuration manager under the solution. Both these options don't work. I still get the same error. I have also tried every cpu option including ARM.

Comment: Did you try to clean the object, delete all bin/obj folders and rebuild?

Comment: yes i tried several cleans. Recreated a couple of new xamarin.forms apps. changed the xamarin forms versions. Still the same issue

Comment: I think you should just right-click on the UWP project, click 'Deploy' and then run

Comment: yes i tried that as well. when i cleaned and then clicked 'Deploy' nothing happened. output showed nothing. Then i tried running, still the same.

Comment: Go to the Project Properties -> Build and select deploy and build checks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to uninstall the existing UWP app from the **Windows Start** menu **> All apps**? Then deploy again from VS. It did the trick for me.

Comment: I didn't exactly find all apps in windows 10. but I could search for it from the start menu and uninstall the app. Then running worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when I create an app packet for win store; Visual studio seem to get hung up building to the packet (project needs to be deployed before it can be started -error).

I solve it by creating a new app packet.